# Replace-error "800a005e" in recordset

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, asp-classic

I have a fully functional website that is running with an access database, so I decided to upgrade it MSSQL, and it turned out to be more difficult than other times.

I have an error called 800a005e

This is my function:

```vb
Function EscapeSpecialCharacters(ByVal strRSContent)
  strRSContent = Replace(strRSContent,"&","&amp;")
  strRSContent = Replace(strRSContent,"É","&Eacute;")
  strRSContent = Replace(strRSContent,"é","&eacute;")

  strRSContent = Replace(strRSContent,"Æ","&AElig;")
  strRSContent = Replace(strRSContent,"Ø","&Oslash;")
  strRSContent = Replace(strRSContent,"Å","&Aring;")
  strRSContent = Replace(strRSContent,"æ","&aelig;")
  strRSContent = Replace(strRSContent,"ø","&oslash;")
  strRSContent = Replace(strRSContent,"å","&aring;")

  EscapeSpecialCharacters = strRSContent
End Function
```

And this is how I call the fun:

```vb
If Not isNull(strPageContent) Then
  Response.Write strPageContent
End If
```

Notice that everything worked normally when I had it on an access database, but now it is another story!

Comment: We don't memorize error codes. Can you tell us the *text* of the error message? Also what is the data type of `strRSContent` and how are you populating that variable from the database?

Comment: Why not HTMLEncode? http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_htmlencode.asp

Comment: Sorry...that was a good one ;-)
The error is this:

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a005e'
Invalid use of Null: 'Replace'
/includes/functions.asp, line 7

And that is the first line _Replace(strRSContent,"&","&amp;")_

Comment: @Remou
I can use _Server.HTMLEncode(RecSetPageContent("pagecontent"))_, but then I have a problem if I have <br/> and other standard tags in my recordset (which could be generated by a WYSIWYG-editor).

Comment: Why not just use utf8 encoding. - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InternationalizationAndClassicASP.aspx

Comment: what is strPageContent? can you Show how you initialize and fill that variable?

Comment: Seriously trying to get around encoding mismatches by replacing the values, I've seen everything now. Here is a tip for the future; `Response.CodePage = 65001` `Response.Charset = "UTF-8"`

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes it's a little frustrating with alle IsEmpty, IsNull, etc... I use a custom Function to avoid these Problems:

```
Public Function IsNullOrEmpty(strString)
  strString = Trim(strString)

  If IsEmpty(strString) Then
    IsNullOrEmpty = True
    Exit Function
  ElseIf StrComp(strString, "") = 0 Then
    IsNullOrEmpty = True
    Exit Function
  ElseIf IsNull(strString) Then
    IsNullOrEmpty = True
    Exit Function
  Else
    IsNullOrEmpty = False
    Exit Function
  End If
End Function

Function EscapeSpecialCharacters(ByVal strRSContent)
    If IsNullOrEmpty(strRSContent) Then
        EscapeSpecialCharacters = ""
        Exit Function
    End If

    strRSContent = Replace(strRSContent,"&","&amp;")
    strRSContent = Replace(strRSContent,"É","&Eacute;")
    strRSContent = Replace(strRSContent,"é","&eacute;")

    strRSContent = Replace(strRSContent,"Æ","&AElig;")
    strRSContent = Replace(strRSContent,"Ø","&Oslash;")
    strRSContent = Replace(strRSContent,"Å","&Aring;")
    strRSContent = Replace(strRSContent,"æ","&aelig;")
    strRSContent = Replace(strRSContent,"ø","&oslash;")
    strRSContent = Replace(strRSContent,"å","&aring;")

    EscapeSpecialCharacters = strRSContent
End Function
```

So in your case this should work regardless the DB:

```
Dim strPageContent
strPageContent = EscapeSpecialCharacters(RecSetPageContent("pagecontent"))
```

Comment: Sorry for my late reply!
Before I get to "If Not isNull(strPageContent) Then Response.Write strPageContent End If", I have this statement:

if RecSetPageContent("pagecontent") <> "" then strPageContent = EscapeSpecialCharacters(RecSetPageContent("pagecontent"))

That is not allowed for some reason...could it be because there are line breaks or codes (<br/>/<a>)? Because a normal "<% Response.Write RecSetPageContent("pagecontent") %>" has no problems...

Comment: No I don't think so, that's not what the error suggests, some DB return Empty, some Null. You could try swapping IsNull to IsEmpty or use my function. See my edit.

Answer (score -1):

Change the function to this to handle the case when the input is null:

```
Function EscapeSpecialCharacters(ByVal strRSContent)
    If IsNull(strRSContent) Then
        EscapeSpecialCharacters = ""
        Exit Function
    End If

    strRSContent = Replace(strRSContent,"&","&amp;")
    strRSContent = Replace(strRSContent,"É","&Eacute;")
    strRSContent = Replace(strRSContent,"é","&eacute;")

    strRSContent = Replace(strRSContent,"Æ","&AElig;")
    strRSContent = Replace(strRSContent,"Ø","&Oslash;")
    strRSContent = Replace(strRSContent,"Å","&Aring;")
    strRSContent = Replace(strRSContent,"æ","&aelig;")
    strRSContent = Replace(strRSContent,"ø","&oslash;")
    strRSContent = Replace(strRSContent,"å","&aring;")

    EscapeSpecialCharacters = strRSContent
End Function
```

Probably Access returned empty string while SQL Server returned Null.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply! It is not that it is null, because if I, among others, SELECT my metas for a specific pageid (or pagecontent), the data should be written to the page, but it doesn't. However, if I make the same query in MSSQL, every information are selected as it should. Therefore, the problem is not the SQL (and I don't have any fields that contains "NULL").

Comment: @Daniel yes it is null, that's the only way `Replace` will throw such an error. Field doesn't need to explicitly have null value in it, lack of any other value is also null. If you will post your SQL maybe I can help you track it down deeper.